# Moment generating function of standard normal

Tags: probability-theory, probability-distributions, random-variables, normal-distribution, moment-generating-functions

As far as I know, given a random variable $X$, we define its moment generating function as
$$M_X(t) = \mathbb{E} \left[ e^{ tX} \right] \ \ , \ t \in \mathbb{R}$$
I read that MGF for a general random variable may not be defined for negative values of $t$. What about if $X \sim N(0,1)$? Can we be sure its MGF is well defined for negative t?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For $X \sim N(0,1)$ we have $Ee^{tX}=e^{t^{2}/2}$ for all real numbers $t$. One way to prove this is to use the characteristic function and use  a basic result from Complex  Analysis [The Identity Theorem].

Comment: Thank you! By the way...I was just wondering, when do we have issues regarding the negativity of $t$?

Comment: If $f(x) =\frac 1 {x^{2}}$ for $x <-1$ and $0$ for $x \geq -1$ then $f$ is a density function. The MGF exists in this case if and only if $t\geq 0$. @YodaAndFriends

Comment: Thank you, that was really helpful!